# Disable writer for virtus attribiute

Tags: ruby

I'm using virtus for attribute definitions in my ruby class:

```
  class Client
    include Virtus.model

    attribute :api_token, String
  end
```

And now I want to disable api_token setter to work only on initialize:

```
client = Client.new(api_token: 'test_token')
client.api_token='new_token' #this should not work
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [custom coercion](https://github.com/solnic/virtus#custom-coercions):

```
class ReadOnlyString < Virtus::Attribute
  def coerce(value)
    raise 'Finalized'
  end
end

class Client
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :api_token, ReadOnlyString
end
```

Other option would be to [override a setter](https://github.com/solnic/virtus#overriding-setters).

`Virtus` has a great readme, by the way.